# Meteor accessing things from route (restivus)

Tags: meteor

Cannot understand why it restrict me accessing Meteor.userId() from route with following error:

> Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions. at AccountsServer.userId (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:82:13) at Object.Meteor.userId (packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js:223:19) at Object.get [as action] (server/main.js:15:28) at Route.share.Route.Route._callEndpoint (packages/nimble_restivus/lib/route.coffee:147:25) at packages/nimble_restivus/lib/route.coffee:59:33 at packages/simple_json-routes.js:98:9

It looks like i forget about publishing something.. but :

> ** You've set up some data subscriptions with Meteor.publish(), but
>
> ** you still have autopublish turned on. Because autopublish is still
>
> ** on, your Meteor.publish() calls won't have much effect. All data
>
> ** will still be sent to all clients.

Very strange, how do you resolve this issue ? I'm new with meteor, but i don't have (google too) any idea how resolve this issue.

Code server/main.js

```
   import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'


Meteor.startup(() => {

      var Api = new Restivus({
        apiPath: 'api/',
        useDefaultAuth: true,
        prettyJson: true
      });
    
      Api.addRoute('test', {
        get: function () {
            console.log(this.userId())
            return {}
          }
      });
    });
```

Comment: It isn't about publishing, you simply don't have access to `Meteor.userId()` there, use `this.userId` instead since it returns same value

Comment: But, it does not work. _TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'userId'_

Comment: Did you import Restivus? It's not in your code. **import { Restivus } from 'meteor/nimble:restivus';**

Comment: It available and work just fine without imports . But it does not matter (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not the Meteor context when you're inside Restivus. So you need to make it explicit:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {

      var self = this;  //<--- here explicitly declare this

      var Api = new Restivus({
        apiPath: 'api/',
        useDefaultAuth: true,
        prettyJson: true
      });

      Api.addRoute('test', {
        get: function () {
            console.log(self.userId())  //<-- use it like this
            return {}
          }
      });
    });
```

Comment: No, it does not work. _TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'userId' at Object.get [as action] (server/main.js:15:26)_

Answer (score 0):

It were difficult day trying solve unsolvable things. I don't know what to think about it, maybe it is my fault trying work with meteor like with another tool. As [Pierre](https://medium.com/@pierrebaz/why-i-won-t-recommend-meteor-anymore-fcec4e478d78#.gsqh8txvq) have said :

> You can’t authenticate a user if the client is not talking over DDP which is really bad when you want to provide API endpoints to your customers.

and, looks like he is right. I'm just trying to work with this tool in wrong way. But i'd say, meteor have to place quote from Pierre to the main page inside of h1 tag at center of page, i'm sure here is a lot of people trying to make unsupported things work with non appropriate tools.

Yeah, it even looks funny.... today )